# Annoying and unwanted Tiny line / Gap on Phonegap App - Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an android app with PhoneGap, HTML, CSS and some jQuery plugins. In the desktop browser, it's fine, normal, and works well. When I compile it with Android SDT to an APK and I install it on a smartphone or tablet, this unwanted tiny line/border/gap appears.

I've spent many days but this still appears:

[image]

**This is my CSS**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none !important;
  position: fixed; /* << i switch into relative, and still not work. */
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;    
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="backgroundColor" value="0x00000000" />
```

It appears that possibly the webview may not be adjusting to fit the screen completely, this should change that line black if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you before, unfortunately, it still appears.
i try to adding with this :

    `
    html {
         background-color:#000;
    }
    `

on my smartphone, it works. The unwanted tiny line is still there but it converted to black color. But on samsung tablet the tiny lie is back to white again. @Dawson Loudon